# TextArea: preserve color and size of pasted text

Tags: html, forms

I have a textarea in a form. The user should paste there different text that comes from other parts of the web or even from other webs. (so I do not know the color or size of that text. I cannot control the origin of that text either) Is there any way to preserve the information of the color and size of the original text when pasted in the textarea?

(I could use jQuery or php if necessary)

Here I have the example simplified to help:http://jsfiddle.net/nbkvb/

CSS:

```
h1 { color:blue; font-family:verdana;font-size:20px; }
p { font-family:verdana; font-size:15px; }
```

HTML:

```
<form action='html-normal.php' method='post'> 
<textarea name='textHtml' rows='15' cols='60'></textarea> <br/> 
<input type='submit' value='submit' /> 
</form> 

<div id=" ">   

<h1>Some title</h1>
<p>some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text,</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextArea is desgined for plain text only. If you want to be able to copy/paste rich text(html) you need to use DIV with `contenteditable="true"` instead of TextArea

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nbkvb/2/

Comment: @Nrc Glad it worked for you. Just note that when you submit the form, DIV's innerHTML is not submitted to the server, you will have to copy it to hidden field - and read value this way on the server. Please check answer as accepted if solution was useful.

Comment: I have been trying to copy to hidden field and I do not find how to do that without losing the information (color and size) can you give me any hint?

Comment: Should be pretty straightforward - before form submits (you can catch form's `onsubmit` event or buttons `onclick` event) just do something like `document.getElementById('yourhiddenfield).value = document.getElementById('yourDiv).innerHTML;` this will copy entire HTML from inside the DIV (including colors, sizes etc.) into hidden field - and when the form is submitted and you read hidden field on the server - you should see all that info.

Comment: At the end I was able to sent the div with the form. Thank you. But I see that if I copy text from different websites to a conteneditable div not always preserve the original color and size. It seems that only Safari does, but not Chrome or Firefox. So, the problem is not solved

Comment: Can u give an example? I've tried a few and copy/paste worked as expected

Comment: For instance I go to: http://www.economist.com/business-finance and I copy the red title of the article and the black/grey subtitle. Then I open Firefox or Chrome and go to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nbkvb/2/ and paste

Comment: Ah yes, if element references an external style that destination page has no access to - that style won't be copied.